# Create a link from a list imported from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanna import data from Firebase to a list in android app and in that list every line to be clickable to a custom activity with data imported from Firebase .
The database is continually changing.
Here how my firebase looks like:

```
Pages
   Page1
   Page2
   Page3
Page1
   Data1
   Data2
   Data3
Page2
   Data1
   Data2
   Data3
Page2
   Data1
   Data2
   Data3
```

I tend to mention that i don't know the number of pages this is continuously changing
This is the Code in the Android Studio

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mCursa);
        mListViewCurse.setAdapter(adapter);

        Firebase curseRef = mRootRef.child("Pages");
        curseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                String message = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.v("E_CHILD_ADDED", message);
                mCursa.add(message);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                String message = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.v("E_CHILD_CHANGED", message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String message = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.v("E_CHILD_REMOVED", message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: what do u mean by create a new activity ??

Comment: @Fay007 Basically I wanna create a link from the list to another page that is automatically generated with data imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot programatically create Activities at runtime. You would need to create and activity, and programatically fill that activity with whatever data was required instead.

Comment: Could you please tell me how could i link from the list to another activity?

Comment: use setOnItemClickListener on your mListViewCurse, then launch the new activity via an intent on this click listener. See documentation here:

Comment: http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/04/start-new-activity-from-android-listview-onitem-clicked.html